# Using jQuery `.attr()` outside the scope of a `.each()` - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the first element with class `.viewer`'s `src` attribute to the value of it's `data-src` attribute. The obvious code doesn't work:

```
$(".viewer").first().show().attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
```

From reading other question on SO, I find you have to do this:

```
$(".viewer").first().show().each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
});
```

It does work, and I do understand why (`this` doesn't refer to the element outside of the scope of the `.each`) - but it seems very weird to run `.each()` after you've already used `.first()`.

Is there a cleaner way to write the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store data you want to reuse in a variable.

```
var viewer = $(".viewer").first().show();
viewer.attr('src', viewer.data('src'));
```

Comment: jQuery has officially made us dumber.

Comment: We had better dump it when ES Harmony is widely adopted.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just use a variable:

```
var elem = $(".viewer").first();
    elem.show().attr('src', elem.attr('data-src'));
```